# Error with struct and return value of function

Tags: c++, xcode, struct

I have struct KhoiGach. I design function "KhoiGach *TaoKhoiGach" 
for return 1 variable with data type "KhoiGach" but it has failed

```
struct KhoiGach
{
   int **arr;
   int Row,Col;
   int iBoard,jBoard;
};


class DesignBrick
{
      public:
          DesignBrick();
          virtual ~DesignBrick();
          int Board[MaxI][MaxJ];
          KhoiGach pkhoigach;
          KhoiGach *TaoKhoiGach(int ID);
};



 KhoiGach DesignBrick :: *TaoKhoiGach(int ID)
 {
     KhoiGach *pkhoigach;
     pkhoigach = new KhoiGach;

    return &pkhoigach;
 }
```

Comment: `return &pkhoigach;`. IMO, you want `return *pkhoigach;`

Comment: Please, define "fail". What is the expected behaviour? What is the observed behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
KhoiGach DesignBrick :: *TaoKhoiGach(int ID)
```

if you want to return pointer `KhoiGach` you need to change it to :

```
KhoiGach *DesignBrick :: TaoKhoiGach(int ID)
```

and here :

```
return &pkhoigach;
```

you are returning the address of your pointer and it's not match your function return value (still I'm assuming you want to return a pointer to `KhoiGach`)

You want this :

```
return pkhoigach;
```